# How to make carousel in react native expo app

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I want to make image text carousel in react native expo app . By using flatlist is one option but i am getting data for carousel from wp rest api. I am getting this warning. So I am looking for alternative

> VirtualizedList: You have a large list that is slow to update - make sure your renderItem function renders components that follow React performance best practices like PureComponent, shouldComponentUpdate, etc.